# Context Menu trigger not firing on TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, wpf-controls

In my WPF application, I have added a TreeView control binding class data to TreeViewItems. I have added a context menu to the treeviewitems. The Handler of the contextMenu is not firing. Here is the XAML code for TreeView.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding pads}" Width="190">
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Rename" Command="{Binding RenameCommand}"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Members.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                                <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PadInfo}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="["></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SlotID}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="] ["></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding WellID}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="]"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                </TreeView>
```

These are the two classes that are binded to the TreeView.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Class to hold the Pads info for a tree
/// </summary>
public class Pad
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Pad()
    {
        this.Members = new ObservableCollection<PadInfo>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the pad
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Members of the pad
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<PadInfo> Members { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class to hold the well and slot IDs snapped to a pad
/// </summary>
public class PadInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Slot ID
    /// </summary>
    public string SlotID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Well ID
    /// </summary>
    public string WellID { get; set; }
}
}
```

This member is bind to the TreeView

```
public List<Pad> pads { get; set; }
```

When I right click on the menu items, the RenameCommand event is not firing. When I change the `<TreeView.ItemTemplate>` to `<TreeViewItems>` the handler is fired but TreeView is not populated with the binded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I am missing important code here about where is your class with the List, where is the command you bind to ? 
Furthermore you are using CommandBinding. This is not like a normal event handler. These are two things in WPF. I think you are missing the Property for your command in your DataContext - class.

Comment: When I use the TreeViewItem in place of TreeView.ItemTemplate the same command fires. So I dont think the problem is with Command or DataContext. 
When I do this 
    <KeyBinding Key="F2"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.RenameCommand}"/>
 
and press F2 the same command fires.

Comment: It not depends on the treeviewitem/template. The difference between Commands and events is that with an event in WPF (or other) you are defining a method that is executed. With Command binding you have a property. And this property contains the action that shall be executed. But this code is missing here.

Comment: here is my Command handler
            private ICommand _RenameCommand;
        public ICommand RenameCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_RenameCommand == null)
                {
                    _RenameCommand = new RelayCommand1((o) => { MessageBox.Show("Rename me"); });
                }
                return _RenameCommand;
            }
        }

Comment: Already tried to add the DataContext.RenameCommand in the code posted in your first post instead of just binding to RenameCommand ?

Comment: yeah I have tried that without any luck. None of the Properteis (Setter Properties) are firing which are mentioned in the TreeViewItemsContainer

Comment: Is there any ouput in the ouput window ?

Comment: Output windows says this.
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TreeView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.RenameCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Then definately your binding expression is not working. But what about your original posted XAML code, and the XAML code you are working with. Right now it is a little bit difficult to determine where exactly the binding fails with what XAML Code. Can you update the posted code and tell us what is working / what not and with what XAML code ? Thanks

Comment: you were right. I was binding my TreeView with Pads class member. And my property was not in the same class. When I added my property to the Pads class, everything worked out great. Many thanks mate :)