# How to bind a string collection to TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In my WPF application, I have added a TreeView. I have a Collection which I want to bind to the parent nodes(TreeViewItems) of the TreeView. Here is my code for doing this.

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" Width="200">
   <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding ElementryNames}"/>
</TreeView>
```

The above code displays a node in the treeView which only displays "Collection" as the text of the TreeView node. What Im doing wrong to get this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind ItemSource to the TreeView and then apply Template for every item.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to specify the Itemssource for your treeview. Then you can define via template for each item from your list how it should be displayed.

With your currently XAML the collection itself is interpreted as item and the default binding for elements is basically the ToString() method.

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I was doing pretty much the same thing. But I am having problem firing Menu item event when I do that. Can you please take a look at this. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510682/context-menu-trigger-not-firing-on-treeviewitem-wpf

Comment: Steven, how many accounts have you on this forum ? Giving you self-reputation by accepting your own answers is not very kind for those people that wanted to help and are spending time on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an item source defined for the treeview. This observable collection can be of a type class. Inside this class you can define a property "ElementryNames" of type string.