# WPF - Need a combination of Tree+Grid, with Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

My application is implemented by a `GridView` inside a `TreeList`.

[image]

Much to my despair, I discovered that the GridView is very primitive, compared to the widely used `DataGrid`. I am considering these two options:

(1) Somehow, I replace the GridView with a DataGrid (which supports Context Menu).

(2) Somehow, I add the Context Menu capability to the existent GridView.

Which of the 2 approaches (or another?) would you recommend?

Source code is much appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: That is a very good question, I would need to implement something very similar.

Comment: HighCore: Are you saying that by adding something called `SharedSizeGroup` the TreeView becomes capable of having Context Menus?

Comment: I just read that the `SharedSizeGroup` is related to column widths: that is the least of my problems right now. I need a `ContextMenu` which is implemented by `DataGrid` but not by `GridView`

Comment: Oh!, I see. I was looking into Context Menus in the wrong place (GridView). Will look again.

Comment: I found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499821/adding-context-menu-to-leaf-node-in-treeview-wpf BUT I need the Context Menu in every row (not in leaf nodes only)

Comment: If you have the cash to spend DevExpress does a control that gives you what you need - the [TreeList Control](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Tree_List/)

Comment: Edited Question: HighCore: Are you saying that by adding something called SharedSizeGroup the `GRIDView` becomes capable of having Context Menus?

Comment: @HighCore: Allow me to apologize profusely. You are the ONLY coder who has actually taken the time to look at my newbie code and have saved my rear bottom a few times. I was finally able to make a minimal case with source code and data. It is here: http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Source-Code-for-High-Core.zip Again: What I need is to add a **Context Menu** to the TOP (tree) panel.

Comment: @HighCore: I erased my wise-asset remarks - Apologies again.

Comment: @swiss_programmer See my answer. BTW, Please edit your question, either posting the relevant code, or at least mentioning that you have created a class called `TreeList` which is a specialized `ListView` that allows hierarchical data. This will help future readers understand the context without having to download your code and look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the linked code, here is the solution:

1 - Add the `ContextMenu` as a Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemsContextMenu" x:Shared="False">
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run>Context Menu Action for Item</Run>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Tag.Name}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>

    <!-- other stuff here -->

</Window.Resources>
```

It is recommended that you set [`x:Shared="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prevent Binding issues related to reusing the resource instance.

2 - Define an [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your TreeList that sets the ContextMenu for the `TreeListItem`s:

```
<tree:TreeList ...>
    <!-- other stuff here -->

    <tree:TreeList.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type tree:TreeListItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemsContextMenu}"/>
         </Style>
    </tree:TreeList.ItemContainerStyle>
</tree:TreeList>
```

Notice that I'm using DataBinding in the `ContextMenu`, which means you have a proper, working `DataContext` in it. You should be able to use `Commands` and other stuff in it.

Comment: HighCore rocks! HighCore rules!!   :^D  ps: Don't go to far... :-)