# C# Windows nested DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to create a DataGridView inside a DataGridView basically "N" number nested DataGridView depending on user need. I am creating the DataGridView programmatically like shown below. Please help me to make the DataGridView nested. Your help will be appreciated greatly.

```
List<CustomObject> dataList = new List<CustomObject> {
            new CustomObject {Id = 100, Name = "Text 1"},
            new CustomObject {Id = 101, Name = "Text 2"},
            new CustomObject {Id = 102, Name = "Text 3"},
            new CustomObject {Id = 103, Name = "Text 4"},
            new CustomObject {Id = 104, Name = "Text 5"},
            new CustomObject {Id = 105, Name = "Text 6"}
        };

        dg = new DataGridView();

        bs = new BindingSource(dataList , string.Empty);
        dg.DataSource = bs;
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a TreeView would be better for this.

Comment: Why i used DataGridView because the data's needs to be displayed in a grid format, rows rearrange, row insert and delete features, drag, mouse hover, leave etc etc also needs to be present...

Comment: The reason I suggest is because a Grid in a Grid is an eyeful. A grid in a grid in a grid is something special. Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24435039/643085) which includes [source code](http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Source-Code-for-High-Core.zip) for a nested TreeView-GridView like custom UI which uses current, relevant .Net Windows UI technologies as opposed to (dinosaur) winforms.